# Can't get Pi to work with a Sony SDM-S74 DVI-D monitor

Tags: raspbian, hardware, video, hdmi

I have just bought a new RaspberryPi that I'm trying to get working with a Sony DVI monitor. I'm hoping someone can help me.

I installed Raspbian on a 8GB card, connected the Pi to a Sony SDM-S74 monitor using a HDMI-to-DVI cable. When I power-up the PI I get nothing displayed on the monitor. The status light on the monitor is amber, indicating no signal.

Three things that I know:

1. The same monitor and hdmi->dvi cable work with my windows 7 laptop's hdmi output, giving me 1280x1024, so I'm confident that cable and monitor are not faulty.
   2 If I plug the Pi into my tv (a Sharp Aquos) using a different hdmi cable then I get a good HD display, so I know that the Pi is generating an hdmi signal.
2. If I edit config.txt and add `hdmi_safe=1` then I get 640x480 vga on the Sony monitor. This is the *only* way I can get anything to display on the monitor.
3. According to the monitor's documentation, it supports DVI-D. The connector on the monitor is identical to the one labelled "DVI-D single link" [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aDVI_Connector_Types.svg).

I tried the following commands from the elinux.org configuration wiki:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -m CEA
Group CEA has 0 modes:
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -m DMT
Group DMT has 0 modes:
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -d edid.dat
Written 128 bytes to edid.dat
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ /opt/vc/bin/edidparser edid.dat
Parsing edid.dat...
HDMI:EDID version 1.3, 0 extensions, screen size 34x27 cm
HDMI:EDID features - videodef 0x80 standby suspend active off; colour encoding:RGB444|YCbCr422; sRGB is not default colourspace; preferred format is native; does not support GTF
HDMI:EDID found monitor range descriptor tag 0xfd
HDMI:EDID monitor range offsets: V min=0, V max=0, H min=0, H max=0
HDMI:EDID monitor range: vertical is 57-63 Hz, horizontal is 28-65 kHz, max pixel clock is 110 MHz
HDMI:EDID monitor range does not support GTF
HDMI:EDID found monitor name descriptor tag 0xfc
HDMI:EDID monitor name is SDM-S74
HDMI:EDID found monitor S/N descriptor tag 0xff
HDMI:EDID found preferred DMT detail timing format: 1280x1024p @ 60 Hz (35)
HDMI:EDID established timing I/II bytes are A1 08 00
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 4, 640x480p @ 60 Hz in established timing I/II
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 9, 800x600p @ 60 Hz in established timing I/II
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 16, 1024x768p @ 60 Hz in established timing I/II
HDMI:EDID standard timings block x 8: 0x8180 8140 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 35, 1280x1024p @ 60 Hz (5:4) in standard timing 0
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 32, 1280x960p @ 60 Hz (4:3) in standard timing 1
HDMI:EDID filtering formats with pixel clock > 162 MHz or h. blanking > 1023
HDMI:EDID best score mode initialised to DMT (4) 640x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 25 MHz (score 18432)
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now DMT (4) 640x480 @ 60 MHz with pixel clock 25 Hz (score 36864)
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now DMT (9) 800x600 @ 60 MHz with pixel clock 40 Hz (score 57600)
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now DMT (16) 1024x768 @ 60 MHz with pixel clock 65 Hz (score 94370)
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now DMT (32) 1280x960 @ 60 MHz with pixel clock 108 Hz (score 172456)
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now DMT (35) 1280x1024 @ 60 MHz with pixel clock 108 Hz (score 5182286)
HDMI:EDID preferred mode remained as DMT (35) 1280x1024p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 108 MHz
HDMI:EDID has only DVI support and no audio support
```

This seems to confirm that I should be using `hdmi_group=2` and `hdmi_mode=35`, but when I add that to config.txt I still get no display.

I've tried probably every combination of `hdmi_drive`, `hdmi_group`, `hdmi_mode`, `hdmi_force_hotplug`, `hdmi_ignore_edid`, `config_hdmi_boost`, and others with no success. The only way I can get anything displayed is with `hdmi_safe` set. What am I doing wrong? Am I wasting my time with this monitor, even though it works with my laptop?

Is there a wiki somewhere with known good config.txt settings for different monitors. Should there be?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

EDIT: Added `config_hdmi_boost` to list of commands tried

Comment: Try this: config_hdmi_boost=4

Comment: @Christian Thanks, but I've already tried that, on its own and in combination with the other config settings I listed. I'll edit the question to clarify that.

Comment: Is it possible instead of "downgrading" the monitor cable to "upgrade" your monitor? Did you try a Dual-Link monitor at the raspberry´s HDMI-Video outlet? Does the pi deliver a HDMI-output that (using a passive HDMI-to-Dual_Link_DBI-Adapter) satisfy a Dual-Link-DVI monitor? catweazle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I now have the Pi working with my Sony monitor.

The problem was that the monitor has a DVI-D single link input connector, but I was using a dual link cable. When I replaced the cable with a single link cable, the monitor started working without requiring any configuration settings.

More information on the difference between single and dual link DVI [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#Technical_overview).

My thanks to those who responded with helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to say a big THANK YOU to Andy Johnson and his Single/Dual link DVI-D suggestion.

My PI4 would never connect to a Sony SDM monitor despite all config files changes I could find on forums. After ordering a new HDMI/DVI cable SINGLE LINK, it worked immediately like a charm.