# Raspberry Pi 3B not booting

Tags: raspbian, boot, boot-issues

So I've attempted to follow the links from R-Pi Troubleshooting. I can't discern a pattern. I see a solid green, short off, long solid green. Then intermediate green flashing for hours, it feels like a successful boot happened.

Here is a video of the [Start up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMK8SDCI2rw). I'm not sure what is happening after ~30 seconds the green light shuts off and will just randomly blink on/off which shouldn't that just be signally SD card activity?

I don't get an output to HDMI even after modifying the config.txt to include
`hdmi_force_hotplug=1` nothing changed.

I plugged in a standard USB keyboard a on boot tried pressing 1/2/3/4 to change the display mode and none-produce an output. Immediately after plugging in the USB my Display does reset it's `NO DEVICE FOUND` error and switch to a black screen before reverting back to `NO DEVICE FOUND`.

I re-formatted the card using SD Card formatter. Then re-imaged the SD card using Win32Disk Imager (from sourceforge). Now I get [this pattern](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ETfiLBIE0Rg). Still confused.

The image I'm working off of is 2016-05-25-raspbian-jessie.zip, I've verfied my SHA1 sum with the download so I'm confident it isn't corrupt. I'm using a SAN Disk Ultra SD card (which is on the list of tested cards and is marked Green) so I believe my SD card is fine.

Comment: What are you using for a power supply?

Comment: It does sound like it is booting successfully but the display is not working.   Is this a new pi?  What exactly is the HDMI jack connected to, an actual HDMI display or something else with an adapter?

Comment: Canakit ACDC converter. Model: DCAR-52A5 (Output 5V 2.5A) Came with this kit https://www.canakit.com/raspberry-pi-3-starter-kit.html

Comment: @goldilocks Male HDMI to Male DVI cable (manufacture is avantek) where it connects to a Dell E2216H monitor

Comment: That is the problem then.  You need to try it with a an actual HDMI display -- although it *may* be a power issue, since those adapters I think draw more than the usual amount (you could try `config_hdmi_boost=7`, do not go higher than that), some people have just plain reported being unable to use them here before.

Comment: @goldilocks `hdmi_boost=7` did not fix the issue. Going to hunt for a HDMI compatible motherboard.

Comment: The HDMI jacks on motherboards are generally outputs...don't do that unless you are sure it isn't or you may damage something.

Comment: I connected to a TV HDMI input via an HDMI/HDMI cable and it worked. So I'm going to revert the `hdmi_boost=7` change. (assuming this works please make a comment about the HDMI-DVI cable being the issue I'll accept it as a solution)

Comment: @goldilocks I can confirm it works without `hdmi_boost=7`

Comment: Actually whoops, I got the name of that option wrong -- see the answer I posted (I've corrected it in my initial comment here too for posterity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of an HDMI -> DVI adapter cable is not guaranteed to work, although one thing you could try is:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
config_hdmi_boost=7
```

Beware that although there are things scattered around the web about the fact that the latter can be set up to 11, [7 is the maximum recommended](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/config-txt.md#config_hdmi_boost) and I am positive someone here has reported rendering the HDMI output permanently defunct after jacking it up too high.

If that doesn't work, you may want to have a look at these Q&As:

[Connecting Monitor via HDMI->DVI Cable does not work](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/36750/5538)

[Can't get Pi to work with a Sony SDM-S74 DVI-D monitor](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/2007/5538)

[Why my HDMI->DVI converter works only when powered from PC?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/43251/5538)

All of which have solutions of different kinds in particular contexts.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **2A-5V adapter** or even 2.5A. Your Pi 3 requires sufficient current as it has a Wi-Fi and Bluetooth modules built-in the Pi board. These modules are current hungry if you don't support the Pi with enough current it will shutdown automatically as a kind of short-circuit protection.

Be aware not to increase the voltage as this will damage the Pi. Keep it 5V.

Comment: I am using a 5V 2.5A converter. Namely a cankit one. Here is a link to it https://www.canakit.com/raspberry-pi-3-starter-kit.html

Comment: I have a few of those supplies.  They've never been a problem as far as I've noticed.

Comment: @Valarauca have you tried HDMI to HDMI instead of DVI?

Comment: @Valarauca the pattern of your green LED is typically perfect. I think it's because the other end of the cable is DVI.